# Multiple Datasets with Like or Contains Keyword

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to filter an expression using Dataset Value along with Like or Contains Statement. I have 7 Datasets(Outline_info, Product_info, Materials_Info, Wiring_info, etc) and each dataset has handful Calculated Fields. For example., "Product_info" dataset has fields like productID, qty, unitofmeasure etc., which are getting populated through stored procedures

I have added the following value in the textbox on the report:

```
=IIF((Fields!productID.Value,"Product_Info") = "J*", ("Jacket: " & First(Fields!productID.Value,"Product_Info")), ("Tops: " & First(Fields!productID.Value,"Product_Info")))
```

In the above expression, I'm checking, if the productID field starts with "J" i.e., `((Fields!productID.Value,"Product_Info") = "J*")`, then I want the Textbox starts with "Jacket: ProductID Value" i.e., `("Jacket: " & First(Fields!productID.Value,"Product_Info"))`, otherwise "Tops: ProductID Value" i.e., `("Tops: " & First(Fields!productID.Value,"Product_Info"))`.

But I'm getting the following Errors while trying to process the report: 
the value expression for the text box "ProductID" refers to the field "ProductID" without specifying a dataset aggregate. when the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a wildcard with "=" so you will have to use the LEFT function like this.

```
=IIF(
    LEFT((Fields!productID.Value,"Product_Info"),1) = "J"
        , "Jacket: " & First(Fields!productID.Value,"Product_Info")
        , "Tops: " & First(Fields!productID.Value,"Product_Info")
)
```

Also make sure that the fields names are spelled correctly, they are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks @Alan Schofield